# less command does not open zip files on debian

Tags: linux, debian, compression, zip, less

Here I am using debian/testing distribution on my machine but there is something interesting.

```
# less file.zip
"./file.zip" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

Do I need to install some extra packages on my machine in order to be able to open zip files on my machine using less command?

Comment: `less` is a pager, it's used for reading text files. ZIP is an archive of possibly multiple files. What do you expect to see when opening a ZIP file with `less`?

Comment: i would expect it, yes. Because on Redhat based distributions, `less` can open compressed files, and i see no `.lesskey` or no alias or no specials parameters to the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lesspipe` tool can transparently convert files to text when you call less on them.  This includes decompressing .gz files and listing the contents of .zip files.  Debian includes `lesspipe` in the `less` package but doesn't automatically configure it.

Add the following to your shell's login script (e.g, `~/.bash_profile`):

```
eval "$(lesspipe)"
```

This should add two environment variables, `LESSOPEN` and `LESSCLOSE`.  Once you've done this, running `less` on a zip file should show you the list of files in the zip file.

Comment: How is it possible to use `less` command itself?

Comment: After you set up `lesspipe`, it will automatically convert files that you view with `less`.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: `unzip -p file.zip | less`

---

Some background

## ZIP

I think the ZIP file format first appeared on MSDOS and then MS Windows. It was primarily a way to gather a group of many files together in an archive and compress the combined data. In other words it creates a multi-file compressed archive. You cannot assume a ZIP file contains a single file and assume that file is a text file.

I recall the compression algorithms used by zip utilities changed over the years, though probably later tools could handle earlier compression algorithms. I think the most common tools for creating ZIP files were originally the PKZIP tools created by Phil Katz at PKWare. Later MS WIndows acquired the ability to create ZIP files natively.

## Unix & Linux

On Unix-like systems the traditional equivalent method was to first gather multiple files together using a tool such as tar to create a `something.tar` file and then separately `compress` it to create a `something.tar.Z` file. Later Gnu's `tar` acquired compression capabilities from Gnu-Zip (`gzip`) and could create a `something.tar.gz` or `something.tgz` in a single operation.

So a file with a filename extension of `.ZIP` is most likely to have originated on Windows not Linux.

If your ZIP file definitely contains a single text file, a general solution would be to pipe the output of an unzip operation into `less`. This depends on having an unzip command that reads your particular flavour of zip compression and has options to write to STDOUT.

Commonly installed tools for viewing text files compressed using some "zip" compression algorithm include `zcat` and `bzless`. The man pages for these say

```
GZIP(1)                                                  General Commands Manual    
NAME
       gzip, gunzip, zcat - compress or expand files

SYNOPSIS
       gzip [ -acdfhklLnNrtvV19 ] [--rsyncable] [-S suffix] [ name ...  ]
       gunzip [ -acfhklLnNrtvV ] [-S suffix] [ name ...  ]
       zcat [ -fhLV ] [ name ...  ]

DESCRIPTION
       Gzip  reduces  the  size of the named files using Lempel-Ziv coding (LZ77).
```

and

```
BZMORE(1)                                                General Commands Manual 

NAME
       bzmore, bzless - file perusal filter for crt viewing of bzip2 compressed text

SYNOPSIS
       bzmore [ name ...  ]
       bzless [ name ...  ]
```

But this depends on the chosen compression utilities knowing the particular compression algorithm used on your zip file.

## PKZIP compatible Unzip

Most likely you need an `unzip` tool that is compatible with the DOS/Windows ZIP format. On some Linux systems you may need to install this first using whatever package manager is appropriate for your distribution. For example `sudo apt install zip`.

```
$ ls -l eg*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rgb rgb 182 Aug 30 19:10 eg.zip

$ unzip -l eg.zip
Archive:  eg.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  2020-08-30 18:50   eg.txt
---------                     -------
       20                     1 file

$ unzip -p eg.zip
hello world
The end

$ unzip -p eg.zip | less
hello world
The end
```

Comment: I see on Ubuntu it is possible to see content of the zip files with less command: `less /usr/share/doc/time/NEWS.gz`. just try on ubuntu please

Comment: @M.J `.gz` (gzip) are not ZIP files. They do compression only and store just contents of a single file. So if you gzip-compress a text file, decompressing it will yield contents of the original file - `less` can display that. ZIP is completely different and your request doesn't make sense for it.

Comment: You see in debian/testing less command doesn't open even gz files! `less /usr/share/doc/timgm6mb-soundfont/changelog.Debian.gz`